# Grep if else statement

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to build a script that will look for changes between two files and action a task if changes have been found.

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

The grep command above displays the differences between the two files but I'm not sure how to combine that with an if statement.

The file contains 11 digit telephone number.

Thanks :)

Comment: Note that the above command is a lot slower (and requires vastly more memory) than alternative means to compare two files. You get some benefits for that speed hit -- order independence, f/e, whereas the most efficient approaches require you to keep your files sorted -- but it's still often not ideal.

Comment: (see [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) for a discussion that includes `comm`, perhaps the most efficient tool for the job, albeit one with the aforementioned sort-order requirement).

Comment: Just use `cmp file1 file2` or `diff file1 file2` depending on your needs.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest avoiding `diff` unless you actually require the generation of a patch file. `diff` does a bunch of work to try to build the shortest possible edit to transform one file into the other, and none of that work is strictly necessary for the use case at hand.

Comment: That `grep` command would fail to report the difference if file2 contained a line that file1 didn't.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is not the right tool to compare files. It will be inefficient, slow and may be buggy.

It would be much more efficient to use `cmp` for this comparison

```bash
if cmp -s file1 file2; then
   echo "same"
else
   echo "different"
fi
```

Comment: Does `md5sum` buy anything over `if cmp -s file1 file2`? `cmp` can stop as soon as it finds a difference; `md5sum` needs to read both files front-to-back, even if there's a difference right at the beginning.

Comment: Indeed I forgot about `cmp`. Fixing it now. Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer to teach `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi` instead of `foo && bar || baz` given the latter's potential for surprises should `bar` fail, but this is certainly the best answer now available.

Comment: Fair point. I converted into `if/else` code

Comment: Could this also print the changes into a file? In my haste I didn't fully think about what I wanted to achieve.

If no changes do nothing
if file two has new entries run SQL insert command with changes
If numbers missing from file 2 compared to file1 run run SQL delete command with the deleted numbers

Comment: It would be better if you open a new question for that differential treatment and running SQL etc so that you get better answers catering that requirement. This question was about finding differences only among 2 files so let's keep that only.

Answer (score -2):

If you intend to do something based on the differences, I mocked up a couple files of phone numbers to generate output from, following your example. This came to mind:

```
OutPut=`grep -vf file2 file1`
if [ -z "$OutPut" ]
then
   echo No Output
else
   for i in $OutPut
   do
      echo Do something with phone number $i
   done
fi
```

Hope that makes sense and is useful.

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). A lot of this will also scale pretty badly should the list of phone numbers be long (no reason it couldn't be measured in megabytes).